# Best starting point for an app where tableview/navigation controller is just one part

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, modalviewcontroller

I've put together an app that uses a table view and navigation controller to display a list of documents (HTML docs) and by clicking on a document title will open up a detail view and display its contents. That works a treat but it will ultimately be part of a bigger app which will have a menu of which this would be just one of the options.

I've done a lot of digging around but am still unsure on the best approach to take for building the overall app. A lot of advice seems to be to use the navigation based application template and push out the menu view and hide the navigation bar but is this really the recommended way to go?

I've read the Apple docs and Modal View controllers sounds like they could be and option but I am then unsure how I would slot in my existing RootViewController etc?

Really appreciate someone taking the time to help get me on the right track

Cheers
Kieron

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a navigation controller is a very common way of structuring this. And as you note, the nav bar itself can be hidden on some view controllers.

Be careful about presenting view controllers modally -- Apple's advice in the HIG is to use modals when you are focusing the user's attention on a certain piece of information or a crucial task -- don't just use them willy-nilly.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the View Controller Programming Guide made the same point about using them modally to 'interrupt the current workflow. I have now got it so that my menu pops up before my navigations controller but doesn't working this way mean that the menu view and any of the other options the user wants to zip in and out of will become part of the navigation stack? I really want the documents section of the app to be the only part that uses the 'features' of the navigation controller so that the user can roam freely.

Comment: Played around some more and now have everything working as I had hoped, Thanks again